# Why the media query is not working as intended

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make responsive divs using media query but as I've written @media to change the flex to 50% at max-width 800px it's not changing that way rather it is working on 720px and also for max-width 480px it's changing on 432px. Why is this happening anyone have any idea ? here's the html and css code:

```
<header class="header">
        <h1>RESPONSIVE GALLERY</h1>
        <p>Picker, pic of the day...</p>
    </header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <img src="img1.png" alt="">
                <img src="img1.png" alt="">
                <img src="img1.png" alt="">
                <img src="img1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="img1.png" alt="">
                <img src="img1.png" alt="">
                <img src="img1.png" alt="">
                <img src="img1.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="img2.png" alt="">
                <img src="img2.png" alt="">
                <img src="img2.png" alt="">
                <img src="img2.png" alt="">
            </div>    
            <div class="col">
                <img src="img2.png" alt="">
                <img src="img2.png" alt="">
                <img src="img2.png" alt="">
                <img src="img2.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

.css

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
}
/* .header{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
} */

.header{
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /* padding: 0 4px; */
}


.col{
    flex:25%;
    /* max-width: 25%; */
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.col img{
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

@media (max-width: 800px){
    .col{
        flex:50%;
        max-width:50%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px){
    .col{
        flex:100%;
        max-width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have the page zoomed in 110%.

Comment: @GuyIncognito thanks I was at 90%

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some extra code to the @media query, try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    .col{
        flex:50%;
        max-width:50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .col{
        flex:100%;
        max-width:100%;
    }
}
```

also check if you have the meta viewport set in your HTML file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: actually i was zoomed out at 90% tha's why and I did have viewport set at device width